# Server is not recognizing VPN IP address, accessing client address directly

Tags: domain-name-system, openvpn, apache-2.4

I have an Ubuntu server on Digital Ocean running Apache as the web server. This server functions both as my web server and as a personal VPN.

I'm trying to set it so that certain directories are only accessible by devices connected to my VPN and by certain other requesters. However, my server doesn't seem to be handling this correctly.

If I go to any IP checker (ipchicken.com, icanhazip.com, dnsleaktest.com, etc.), it shows my IP address as the IP of the Digital Ocean server where my VPN is hosted, 104.2**.**.*

If I disconnect from my VPN, it shows my ISP provided IP address of 108.1**.*.***

I put a PHP script on my server that simply prints out the `$_SERVER` variable. For some reason, regardless of whether or not I'm connected to my VPN, this script *always* shows `[REMOTE_ADDR] => 108.1**.*.***`.

What could be causing this? Is it because the VPN is on the same server as Apache, so Apache is receiving the connection before it runs through the VPN or something? How can I fix this?

Comment: this answer might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/916157/1823684

Answer (score 0):

"Why aren't I using a VPN to reach the other end of that same VPN?"

You can't connect *to* a VPN *through* that same VPN. That would involve infinite recursion. The IP address of the VPN endpoint must be reachable directly or the VPN itself wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm not connecting to my VPN through my VPN. I'm connected to my VPN on port 1193 and Apache is running on 443. When I type in the URL for my website, the VPN has to go out and look up the IP address like it does for any other site, so why wouldn't it be able to run the traffic from one port to another when it's two completely different entities that happen to share one machine.

Comment: For precisely the reason I explained -- routing traffic to the VPN endpoint through the VPN would destroy the VPN.